# Read and format data in java

Tags: java, data-structures, formatting

I have an assignment where I have to read data from a text file. The data looks like this in the file:

`1946-01-01;07:00:00;-1.8;G
1946-01-01;13:00:00;-1.0;G
1946-01-01;18:00:00;-1.9;G
1946-01-02;07:00:00;-1.7;G`

I want to format the data and put it in an appropriate data structure so that I then can search for average temperature for all dates between two dates. What is the simplest way to format this data when my code is:

```
package algo.weatherdata;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Provides methods to retrieve temperature data from a weather station file.    
 */
public class WeatherDataHandler {
    /**
     * Load weather data from file.
     * 
     * @param filePath path to file with weather data
     * @throws IOException if there is a problem while reading the file
     */
    public void loadData(String filePath) throws IOException {
        //Read all weather data
        List<String> fileData = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(filePath));

        /**
         * TODO: Format data and put it in appropriate data structure.
         */


    }
```

Comment: please try more to post some more code before asking for a solution. Show some effort to solve the problem, and we can tell you what's wrong. Right now, it's just method declarations without actual code. Some useful method that would get you started is the String's split() method. You can define the delimiter to be ';'. Before that, google for "read file in java"

Comment: What is `G` mean?

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over your lines and separate each line by a delimiter (in your case `;`):

```
public void loadData(String filePath) throws IOException {
    List<String> fileData = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(filePath));

    String[] lineValues = str.split(";");
    // line values are stored in this array
}
```

Then you can do with the array as you like (store them, process them).

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume the following class that will contain weather data:

```
public class WeatherData {

    private LocalDateTime dateTime;
    private double temperature;
    private String tag;            // I don't really know what is 'G' mean

    public WeatherData(LocalDateTime dateTime, double temperature, String tag) {
        this.dateTime = dateTime;
        this.temperature = temperature;
        this.tag = tag;
    }
}
```

Next, we analyze the data file into the current structure and collect them all into a list:

```
private List<WeatherData> weatherData = new ArrayList<>();

public void loadData(String filePath) throws IOException {
    List<String> fileData = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(filePath));
    for(String str : fileData) {
        List<String> parsed = parseData(str);
        LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.of(dateOf(parsed.get(0)), 
                                                  timeOf(parsed.get(1)));
        double temperature = Double.parseDouble(parsed.get(2));
        String tag = parsed.get(3);

        WeatherData weather = new WeatherData(dateTime, temperature, tag);
        weatherData.add(weather);
    }

}

private List<String> parseData(String s) {
    return Arrays.asList(s.split(";"));
}

private LocalDate dateOf(String date) {
    return LocalDate.parse(date);
}

private LocalTime timeOf(String time) {
    return LocalTime.parse(time);
}
```

And then you could work with a list to search between dates and calculate the average temperature

Answer (score 0):

I have tried above **Dinar Zaripov** piece of code in my work space with addition of generating getters methods for dateTime, temperature and tag.

*Continuation after for loop*

```
private static float averageTemperature(List<WeaterData> weatherData) 
{

        float sum = 0; // Variable to store the sum
        float count = 0; // Variable to keep the count

        if (weatherList != null) {
            for (WeaterData averageWeather : weatherData) {
                float value = averageWeather.getTemperature();
                System.out.println(value);
                if (value <= 0) { // Check if the number is negative
                    sum += value; // Add the value to the current sum
                    count++; // Increment the count by 1
                }
            }

        }
        return (count > 0) ? (sum /count) : 0; // Calculate the average if there were any negative numbers
    }
```

But I am getting average as ** average::1.5999999 ** 
However as per the math it should be 1.6. could someone tell me how ? or this is correct ?

when I give below data , I am getting correct average :)

```
1946-01-01;07:00:00;-1.8;A
** 1946-01-01;13:00:00;-1.1; B**
1946-01-01;18:00:00;-1.9;C
1946-01-02;07:00:00;-1.7;D
```